# Mongoose save() doesn't actually save

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, save

I am trying to find my record, update it, and save it. I can see the data updated and it can still show the updated data inside the callback of save(). However, when I go to the database, it is actually **not** updated:

```
Skills.findOne({ skillsCat: req.body.skillsCat }, (err, gets)=> {
  if (err) {
      res.send(err)
      return
  }

  if (gets && gets.skillName.indexOf(req.body.skillName) !== -1) {
    // Here I update my data
    gets.percent[gets.skillName.indexOf(req.body.skillName)] = req.body.percent
    Console.log(gets);   // Here I can see the data is updated

    return gets.save((err, updated)=> {
      Console.log(updated);   // Here I can see the data is updated
      if (err) { return }
      res.json({
        message: 'Skill updated successfully',
        data: updated
      })
    })

  } else {
    return
  }
})
```

Is there anyone encounter similar issues before and help me out with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code :

```
gets.percent[gets.skillName.indexOf(req.body.skillName)] = req.body.percent
Console.log(gets);   // Here I can see the data is updated

//Notice that 'fieldname' is the name of actual field in database
 gets.markModified('fieldname');

return gets.save((err, updated)=> {
  Console.log(updated);   // Here I can see the data is updated
  if (err) { return }
  res.json({
    message: 'Skill updated successfully',
    data: updated
  })
})
```